# how to implement permissions in angular2?

Tags: angular, permissions

I am developping an app in angular2, and i need to implement permissions with some detailed features:

- read-only sections for not logged in users
- enable/disable buttons if the user is logged in
- enable/disable buttons and sections if the user is the author of the content

I have read about [using guards for routes](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html), but i don't want to block whole routes, just some components or parts of a component.

So what's the best way to do that, other than just adding a bunch of if statements in my templates?